# Validating @RequestParam in Spring 3 MVC

Tags: java, spring, validation, data-binding, spring-mvc

How do I validate Spring @RequestParam so that they are in BindingResult with out having to use some sort of POJO transfer object (@ModelAttribute)?

I could use MapBindingResult and put the request parameters in that but then I have to get that binding result into the model.

Which I can do with org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.MODEL_KEY_PREFIX + name.

Is there a better way to bind and validate request parameters (instead of making another POJO)?

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Spring MVC 3.0 or later, you can use the [declarative validation support](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validation-mvc) Spring provides. You would then declare the validation restrictions on the model bean and add the `@Valid` annotation to your form backing bean as described in the chapter ["Spring Validation"](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validation-beanvalidation) in the reference docs.

If you add a `BindingResult` parameter directly after the bean being validated, you can then check for validation errors in your controller:

```
// .. in the bean class
public class MyBean {
    @NotNull
    private String name;
    // ..
}

// .. in the @Controller
public ModelAndView doSomething(@Valid MyBean data, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) { 
        // back to form
    }
    // do something with the bean
}
```

Comment: that is what I'm trying to avoid. I dont want or need another forming back object.

Comment: Ah, okay. Then I don't see the motivation for `BindingResult` (and the `DataBinder` used internally) since they apply to binding request data to form/command objects only. If you try to inspect individual `@RequestParam` values (e. g. primitives or Strings), you could use an aspect to pre-fill a custom `BindingResult` or maybe write a specific `HandlerInterceptor` who performs additional action on the request parameters before it hits the controller.

Comment: the reason I want use the BindingResult is that it handles error messaging and i18n. For now I just made another transfer object.